# Results only returned for a specific folder in a Sharepoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint

We have an integration that uses the Sharepoint REST API to Create and Query files and folders in a Sharepoint Online document library.

The integration creates a folder structure whenever a new Item Code is added within an SAP Application.

When navigating to an Item record in SAP we query the files for that item from the document library to display in SAP.

The issue we have is that the integration is only returning results for the very first folder we created.  Files within other folders are not returned even though the permissions appear the same.

The structure of the site is

- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **A**>/Media/Web/
- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **A**>/Documents/Internal/
- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **A**>/Media/Stickers/
- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **B**>/Media/Web/
- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **B**>/Media/Stickers/
- /Shared Documents/SAP_Items/<item code
  **B**>/Documents/Internal/
- etc...

The code below returns all files within the folder and subfolders of the specified item code.  However, it is only working for the first folder we created in the document library.

The folder structure, files and their permissions look correct (the same as the item that is working) and I have tried re-indexing the library.  I have also double-triple-quadruple checked that there are no values hardcoded in the calling code :)

The following is the code snippet we are using to return the results.  It is part of a class library that is call by the SAP Application.

```
private const string constSiteDomain = "our domain";
private const string constSiteAddress = "our site address";
private const string constWebAPI = "_api/web";
private static readonly string _domainUrl = string.Format("https://{0}/", constSiteDomain);
private static readonly string _fmsSiteUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}/", _domainUrl, constSiteAddress);
private static readonly string _sapItemsUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}/", _fmsSiteUrl, constWebAPI);

public static string GetSharepointFilesForItemCode(string itemCode, string subPath = "", int summarizeFolders = 1)
{
    string getFilesURL = string.Format("{0}Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/RenderListDataAsStream?viewid=9ca7ac23-97f3-45ad-8d41-4a68fb23657d", _sapItemsUrl);
    string fileContents = string.Empty;
    using (HttpRequestMessage getDocumentsRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, getFilesURI))
    {
        getDocumentsRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", BearerToken));                    
        getDocumentsRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata");

        string serverRelativeUrl = string.Format("/sites/FMS/Shared Documents/SAP_Items/{0}/{1}", itemCode, subPath);
        string viewXml = string.Concat(
            "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">",
            "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\"/><Value Type=\"Number\">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
            "<RowLimit Paged=\"TRUE\">1000</RowLimit>",
            "<ViewFields>",
            "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/>",
            "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>",
            "<FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\"/>",
            "<FieldRef Name=\"FileRef.urlencode\"/>",
            "<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\"/>",
            "</ViewFields>",
            "</View>");


        var renderListDataParameter = new
        {
            parameters = new
            {
                FolderServerRelativeUrl = serverRelativeUrl,                            
                ViewXml = viewXml,
                AddRequiredFields = true
            }
        };

        string dataParameterString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(renderListDataParameter);

        StringContent payloadContent = new StringContent(dataParameterString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        getDocumentsRequest.Content = payloadContent;

        using (HttpResponseMessage getDocumentsResponse = _httpClient.SendAsync(getDocumentsRequest).Result)
        {
            getDocumentsResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            fileContents = getDocumentsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            // Note, the fileContents here is populate but has no rows in the rows array for the failing items
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContents))
        throw new Exception("No files found");

    JsonNode data = JsonNode.Parse(fileContents);
    JsonArray rowData = data["Row"].AsArray();
    foreach (JsonNode row in rowData)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Any insights or suggestions appreciated.

Cheers,

Sean

I have tried the following...

- Ensured that the Site and Document Library are set to be searchable.
- Re-indexed the document library.
- Validated that the code calling the code snippet is passing through the correct item codes.
- Search Sharepoint for documents and can find documents for all item codes